# Can I replace my Intel core I5 Processor with an Intel xeon 12 core Processor?

Tags: cpu

I thought about scrapping my old gaming computer and buying a new one with a much faster processor, but then I realize that might be a lot of money. Is it possible to replace my old processor with a much more faster one? Thanks for help.

Comment: What motherboard do you have, what exact processor model do you have, and what socket does it use (can be checked by model on Intel ARK)?

Comment: NO is the answer, you can ignore the attempted answers below. And  this kind of questions are really poor and show lazyness. This is something you can easily Google or just check the supported CPUs for any given motherboard in the manufacturer's website or user's manual. The socket type is the first but not the only specification to consider. Without knowing the exact reference of the CPUs this question CAN'T be answered.

Answer (score 2):

It is but there are compatibilities that your new CPU will need to meet to be able to be used with your existing motherboard.

Those compatibilities are mostly limited to Motherboard Socket and Chipset.
The Socket is the CPU connector on the motherboard and the chipset is the main controller in between the Memory, CPU and the IO Bus/'s.

This is how you can determine potential processes that are available:
Example Motherboard:
[Asus Prime Z370-A](https://www.asus.com/au/Motherboards/PRIME-Z370-A/specifications/)
Search online for motherboard manufacturer and model for specs web page. You can find your motherboard model by looking at the circuit board printing inside the computer case.

In this example I can see it is a LGA 1151 Socket and Intel Z370 Chipset. Asus and likely most other manufacturers will provide CPU compatibility lists on their product pages.

[PCPartPicker](https://pcpartpicker.com/) is one possible tool for identifying CPUs matching socket (Individual Parts > CPU > Filter) and with this information you can research perhaps via your preferred search engine the compatibility or lack thereof of a potential CPU candidate.

Note: Replacing a computer CPU can be a daunting task with the potential for breaking the motherboard or CPU if not performed correctly. Perhaps review videos of the process online and if you don't feel comfortable seek your local custom build computer store for assistance.

Answer (score -2):

Without knowing the specifics, the answer is maybe. Do this:

1. Find out online what your current CPU’s socket is. E.g. core i7 35xx (or so) is a socket LGA1155.
2. Then google, “best cpu for socket x” or motherboard. E.g LGA1155 or your current proc.
3. Research the heck out of it before buying your upgraded processor. Don’t forget about all other stuff like thermal paste and cooling, etc.